# Replace two for loops using tidyverse (dplyr and purrr)

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr

I have a tibble

```
raw.tb
#> # A tibble: 10 x 4
#>       geno    ind     X     Y
#>  *  <fctr> <fctr> <int> <int>
#>  1 san1w16     A1   467   383
#>  2 san1w16     A1   465   378
#>  3 san1w16     B1   464   378
#>  4 san1w16     B1   464   377
#>  5 san2w16     A1   464   376
#>  6 san2w16     A1   464   375
#>  7 san2w16     B1   463   375
#>  8 san2w16     B1   463   374
#>  9 san3w16     A1   463   373
#> 10 san3w16     A1   463   372
```

I would like to replace the usage of two `for` loops using tidyverse. I am working with a function that requires a 2x2 matrix (It could be any function - in this specific case it is momocs::coo_rotate).

What i wish to do can be written like that in base R:

```
for(g in unique(raw.tb$geno)){
   for(i in unique(raw.tb[raw.tb$geno == g,]$ind){     
      raw.tb[raw.tb$geno == g & raw.tb$ind == i,c(3,4)] = some.function.for.a.matrix(raw.tb[raw.tb$geno == g & raw.tb$ind == i,c(3,4)])
   }
   }
```

I'm guessing this can be done using the tidyverse, however I have looked at using `group_by()` with `do()`, and `nest` with `map` and I cannot make it work.

Comment: Looks like you need a group by summary

Comment: You mean use `dplyr::summarise`?

Comment: your loops does not work? Could you post your desired outcome?

Comment: yes, that is right

Comment: @EricFail I just tried this loop and it works: `for(g in unique(raw.tb$geno)){
  for(i in unique(raw.tb[raw.tb$geno == g,]$ind)){
    raw.tb[raw.tb$geno == g & raw.tb$ind == i,c(3,4)] = 
      t( raw.tb[raw.tb$geno == g & raw.tb$ind == i,c(3,4)])
  }
}` @akrun, the problem with `summarise` if I understand what it does, is that it returns one value per group, whereas I wish to return a matrix of the same size as the matrix of my group

Comment: @AP25 what you posted here in the comment runs, but produce no output. I'm happy to help, but I'm still not sure what your desired outcome is.

Comment: @EricFail It transposes the matrix for each ind of a given geno. I would like to do the same but using tidyverse

Comment: like this `raw.tb %>% group_by(geno) %>% gather(XY, Value, -geno, -ind) %>% arrange(geno, ind)`

Comment: Thanks that looks great. However what I was saying is that I'm using `t()` just as an example of a function that applies to matrices since the actual function i wish to use comes from a package that is not used by a lot of people. I was taking that example since the function i wish to use only work with matrices (momocs::coo_rotate). Basically, that function rotates X,Y coordinates (arranged in a nx2 matrix) by theta degrees. I just think my problem could apply to any function that works with matrices (or df). The real problem for me is subsetting my df over two factors in a for loop fashion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. Hope my answer will make things clearer. My apologies to @EricFail for not making this clearer

Basically I wrote a function which given a matrix of x,y coordinates rotates the coordinates using the first and last points as baseline. I am not detailing that function since it is long and is not the point here, but basically, the function is of the type:

```
rotate.coord <- function(mat){
  for(i in 1:dim(mat)[1]{
    x1=(dim(coord.rot)[1])
    x2=1
    .
    .
    (theta is computed based on x1 and x2)
    .
    .
    xn=mat[z,1]*cos(theta)+mat[z,2]*sin(theta)
    yn=-mat[z,1]*sin(theta)+mat[z,2]*cos(theta)
    mat[z,1]=xn
    mat[z,2]=yn
    }
    mat = as_tibble(mat)
    return(mat)
}
```

Having:

```
raw.tb
#> # A tibble: 10 x 4
#>       geno    ind     X     Y
#>  *  <fctr> <fctr> <int> <int>
#>  1 san1w16     A1   467   383
#>  2 san1w16     A1   465   378
#>  3 san1w16     B1   464   378
#>  4 san1w16     B1   464   377
#>  5 san2w16     A1   464   376
#>  6 san2w16     A1   464   375
#>  7 san2w16     B1   463   375
#>  8 san2w16     B1   463   374
#>  9 san3w16     A1   463   373
#> 10 san3w16     A1   463   372
```

I wanted to do

```
raw.nt <- raw.tb %>% 
 group_by(geno,ind) %>% 
 nest()

raw.nt2 <- raw.nt %>% 
  mutate(rot = map(data,rotate.coo))
```

Which creates a new nested tibble where the `raw.nt2$rot` for each group is the rotated matrix from each group of `raw.nt$data`

Answer (score 1):

I am somewhat guessing as it's not clear to me exactly what you are looking to do.

```
raw.tb <- structure(list(geno = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "san1w16", class = "factor"), ind = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 1L), .Label = c("A1", "B1", "C1", 
"D1", "E1"), class = "factor"), X = c(467L, 465L, 464L, 464L, 
464L, 464L, 463L, 463L, 463L, 463L), Y = c(383L, 378L, 378L, 
377L, 376L, 375L, 375L, 374L, 373L, 372L)), .Names = c("geno", 
"ind", "X", "Y"), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", 
"7", "8", "9", "10"), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
)) %>% as_tibble(); raw.tb 
#> # A tibble: 10 x 4
#>       geno    ind     X     Y
#>  *  <fctr> <fctr> <int> <int>
#>  1 san1w16     A1   467   383
#>  2 san1w16     A1   465   378
#>  3 san1w16     B1   464   378
#>  4 san1w16     B1   464   377
#>  5 san1w16     C1   464   376
#>  6 san1w16     C1   464   375
#>  7 san1w16     D1   463   375
#>  8 san1w16     D1   463   374
#>  9 san1w16     E1   463   373
#> 10 san1w16     A1   463   372
```

something like this,

```
raw.tb %>% group_by(geno) %>% gather(XY, Value, -geno, -ind) %>% arrange(geno, ind)
#> # A tibble: 20 x 4
#> # Groups:   geno [1]
#>       geno    ind    XY Value
#>     <fctr> <fctr> <chr> <int>
#>  1 san1w16     A1     X   467
#>  2 san1w16     A1     X   465
#>  3 san1w16     A1     X   463
#>  4 san1w16     A1     Y   383
#>  5 san1w16     A1     Y   378
#>  6 san1w16     A1     Y   372
#>  7 san1w16     B1     X   464
#>  8 san1w16     B1     X   464
#>  9 san1w16     B1     Y   378
#> 10 san1w16     B1     Y   377
#> 11 san1w16     C1     X   464
#> 12 san1w16     C1     X   464
#> 13 san1w16     C1     Y   376
#> 14 san1w16     C1     Y   375
#> 15 san1w16     D1     X   463
#> 16 san1w16     D1     X   463
#> 17 san1w16     D1     Y   375
#> 18 san1w16     D1     Y   374
#> 19 san1w16     E1     X   463
#> 20 san1w16     E1     Y   373
```

from there you can apply alommost any function. Here some `summarise` as suggeted by  akrun

```
raw.tb %>% group_by(geno) %>% gather(XY, Value, -geno, -ind) %>%
           arrange(geno, ind) %>% group_by(ind, geno, XY)  %>%
           summarise(Value = mean(Value))
#> # A tibble: 10 x 4
#> # Groups:   ind, geno [?]
#>       ind    geno    XY    Value
#>    <fctr>  <fctr> <chr>    <dbl>
#>  1     A1 san1w16     X 465.0000
#>  2     A1 san1w16     Y 377.6667
#>  3     B1 san1w16     X 464.0000
#>  4     B1 san1w16     Y 377.5000
#>  5     C1 san1w16     X 464.0000
#>  6     C1 san1w16     Y 375.5000
#>  7     D1 san1w16     X 463.0000
#>  8     D1 san1w16     Y 374.5000
#>  9     E1 san1w16     X 463.0000
#> 10     E1 san1w16     Y 373.0000
```

or maybe

```
raw.tb %>% group_by(geno) %>% gather(XY, Value, -geno, -ind) %>%
           arrange(geno, ind) %>% group_by(ind, geno)  %>%
           summarise(Value = mean(Value))
#> # A tibble: 5 x 3
#> # Groups:   ind [?]
#>      ind    geno    Value
#>   <fctr>  <fctr>    <dbl>
#> 1     A1 san1w16 421.3333
#> 2     B1 san1w16 420.7500
#> 3     C1 san1w16 419.7500
#> 4     D1 san1w16 418.7500
#> 5     E1 san1w16 418.0000
```

Comment: I was pretty much looking for the equivalent tidyverse of: 'toto=as.list(split(raw.tb[,c(3,4)],list(raw.tb$ind,raw.tb$geno)))
toto2=lapply(toto,some.function.for.a.matrix)'

Comment: could you possible include that, including the output, in your question?  I want to make sure we get the same output.